# How to use google transliteration API in bootstrap tags input?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, transliteration

I am trying to use google transliteration API in the input field which i have made a bootstrap tags input but the transliteration API is not working.If i remove the bootstrap tags input from my input field the transliteration API works but i need both the bootstrap tags input as well as the transliteration API.

Here is my code of implementation.

Write your tags comma seperated:

```
        <p>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tag_widget" value=""  style="width:100px;" id="tag_widget" data-role="tagsinput">

        </p> 

        <script type="text/javascript">      

     // Load the Google Transliteration API      

     google.load("elements", "1", {            

          packages: "transliteration"          

      });



var lang= decodeURIComponent("ne");

var e= 1;



  function onLoad() {

    var options = {

      sourceLanguage: 'en',            

      destinationLanguage: ['ne'],    //'hi','kn','ml','ta','te'

      shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',   

      transliterationEnabled: e

    };



    var control =

        new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);



     var textArea=document.getElementById("tag_widget");
    //var textArea=$('.bootstrap-tagsinput span').val();

    var ids = [textArea];

    control.makeTransliteratable(ids);

     control.showControl('translControl');  
     $('#tag_widget').tagsinput('refresh');        

  }

  google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

assets/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput.js">

Answer (score 0):

You can try id='ids' in between input ta

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="tag_widget" value="" style="width:100px;" id="ids" data-role="tagsinput">
```